# React.js: Will multiple async setState method calls always re-render after and impact performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, setstate

I have seen a React setState method with a callback, which means that the callback will be executed after it is ensured that the new state has been set and the component was re-rendered, e.g this example:

```
this.setState({value: event.target.value}, function () {
    console.log(this.state.value);
}); //new state will be logged to console after it was set and rendered
```

now, if I am not totally wrong, the same thing can be implemented using async 
functions:

```
async someFunction(){
await this.setState({value: event.target.value});
console.log(this.state.value);
}
```

My question now is, will it impact performance if I use multiple await setState calls in one function? will it re-render after each setState call and wait for it to finish the rendering process, and then execute the net await setState call etc. and possibly create performance issues? e.g:

```
async someFunction(){
await this.setState({value: event.target.value});
let result = await someAPICall();
await this.setState({resultApiCall: result});
await.....
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you are totally wrong :) `setState` does not return a promise, therefore you can't just `await` it. For sure you can wrap the callback into a promise, but you probably don't need that (as you usually don't need to wait for a rerender).

> will it impact performance if I use multiple await setState calls in one function?

Sure. Calling a function twice is estimatedly twice as slow as calling it once.

> will it re-render after each setState call and wait for it to finish the rendering process, and then [go on]?

Yes, if you would `await` a Promise, like this:

```
 await new Promise(resolve => this.setState(/*...*/, resolve));
```

> and possibly create performance issues?

No, probably not. Calling `setState` will execute *very fast*, you have to call it hundreds of times to impact performance.

Comment: hm but I thought setState is asynchronous, so I'm not sure how its implemented, but at least I thought like with all async operations, you can then just await it?

Comment: No, callbacks are asynchronous. You can't just `await` functions that take a callback. You can only `await` Promises.

Comment: @user2774480 setState is asynchronous. You should familiarize yourself with synchronous and asynchronous JavaScript code because you clearly do not understand what these words mean in JS context.

Comment: ok thanks for the info, then I am probably only confusing static callbacks and Promises...